# global costmap position

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap, global-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm new to ROS and I'm trying to get my robot simulation in gazebo work with the navigation stack. I've followed the navigation stack tutorials but when I set a goal position in the rviz, I get the error:

```
[ WARN] [1405397031.898957310, 340.132000000]: The robot's start position is off the global costmap. Planning will always fail, are you sure the robot has been properly localized?
```

Here are my navigation stack configurations:

costmap_common_params:

```
obstacle_range: 2.5
raytrace_range: 3.0
footprint: [[-0.2,-0.2],[-0.2,0.2], [0.2, 0.2], [0.2,-0.2]]
#robot_radius: 0.20
inflation_radius: 0.55

observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor

laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: lms100, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /p3dx/laser/scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

global_costmap_params:

```
global_frame: /map
robot_base_frame: base_link
update_frequency: 5.0
static_map: true
```

local_costmap_params:

```
global_frame: odom
robot_base_frame: base_link
update_frequency: 5.0
publish_frequency: 2.0
static_map: false
rolling_window: true
width: 6.0
height: 6.0
resolution: 0.05


transform_tolerance: 0.8 # seconds
```

base_local_planner_params:

```
TrajectoryPlannerROS:
  max_vel_x: 0.45
  min_vel_x: 0.1
  max_rotational_vel: 1.0
  min_in_place_rotational_vel: 0.4

  acc_lim_th: 3.2
  acc_lim_x: 2.5
  acc_lim_y: 2.5

  holonomic_robot: false
```

move_base.launch:

```
<launch>
  <master auto="start"/>

  <!-- Run the map server -->
<!-- <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find p3dx_description)/launch/map.yaml my_map" output="screen"/>   -->

  <!--- Run AMCL -->
 
  <include file="$(find amcl)/examples/amcl_omni.launch" />
 <!-- <include file="$(find erratic_navigation)/navigation_slam/slam_gmapping.launch" /> -->
  
  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find p3dx_description)/launch/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find p3dx_description)/launch/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find p3dx_description)/launch/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find p3dx_description)/launch/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find p3dx_description)/launch/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

gazebo.launch which contains gmapping:

```
<launch>

    <!-- these are the arguments you can pass this launch file, for example 
        paused:=true -->
    <arg name="paused" default="false" />
    <arg name="use_sim_time" default="true" />
    <arg name="gui" default="true" />
    <arg name="headless" default="false" />
    <arg name="debug" default="false" />

    <!-- We resume the logic in empty_world.launch, changing only the name of 
        the world to be launched -->
    <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
        <arg name="world_name" value="$(find p3dx_gazebo)/worlds/p3dx.world" />
        <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)" />
        <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)" />
        <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)" />
        <arg name="use_sim_time" value="$(arg use_sim_time)" />
        <arg name="headless" value="$(arg headless)" />
        
    </include>

    <!-- Load the URDF into the ROS Parameter Server -->
    <param name="robot_description"
        command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find p3dx_description)/urdf/pioneer3dx.xacro'" />

    <!-- Run a python script to the send a service call to gazebo_ros to spawn 
        a URDF robot -->
    <node name="urdf_spawner" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model"
        respawn="false" output="screen" args="-urdf -model p3dx -param robot_description" />

    <!-- ros_control p3rd launch file -->
    <!-- <include file="$(find p3dx_control)/launch/control.launch" /> -->


<!-- kasra -->
    
    <node pkg="p3dx_gazebo" name="mimic_cmd_vel" type="mimic_cmd_vel"  />
    
      <!-- convert joint states to TF transforms for rviz, etc -->
  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher"
    respawn="false" output="screen">
    <remap from="/joint_states" to="/p3dx/joint_states" />
  </node>
  <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" >
  </node>
  <node pkg="p3dx_gazebo" name="laser_tf_broadcaster" type="laser_tf_broadcaster"  />
  <node pkg="gmapping" name="slam_gmapping" type="slam_gmapping"   args="scan:=/p3dx/laser/scan"/>
    
</launch>
```

When I add the global_costmap to the rviz it shows as a square which my robot is on one of its corners and that's why I get that error:

lamoo.persiangig.com/image/ros/rviz.png

And here are my rqt_gragh and tf_tree:

lamoo.persiangig.com/image/ros/graph.png

lamoo.persiangig.com/image/ros/tf_tree.png

Does anyone now how can I control the position of the global_costmap? the regular map which comes from the laserScan looks correct but the global_costmap as you see in the picture does not contain the robot. I appreciate any help in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186575/global-costmap-position/) by [Kasra](https://answers.ros.org/users/19256/kasra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2014-07-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found what's causing the problem. For whatever reason I couldn't put the namespace in the beginning of the param files like putting the "global_costmap" at the start point of the "global_costmap_params.yaml". It's the way it is in the tutorials but it just didn't work for me. So I added these namespaces to the move_base.launch and now I see my robot in center of the global_costmap. Thank you David,  looking at the output of "rosparam get /move_base" helped me to figure it out.

---

Originally posted by [Kasra](https://answers.ros.org/users/19256/kasra/) with karma: 86 on 2014-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using gmapping, you have to set static map to false in the global costmap param, since you are not using any previous created map, you are using the map created with slam gmapping. An example of how to set this could be:

static_map: false
width: 40.0
height: 40.0
origin_x: -20.0
origin_y: -20.0

Note that the origin of the map is the center of it. Also you can use any size you want for it.

---

Originally posted by [donmrsir](https://answers.ros.org/users/19553/donmrsir/) with karma: 363 on 2014-07-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kasra](https://answers.ros.org/users/19256/kasra/) on 2014-07-15**:
Thanks you. I made the changes but still when I add the global_costmap to the rviz, it shows it in the the same place. It seems writing "width: 40.0 height: 40.0 origin_x: -20.0 origin_y: -20.0" hasn't changed anything, because its origin is still (0, 0, 0) and weight=heigh=200

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-07-15**:
Which namespace did you set those parameters in?

**Comment by [Kasra](https://answers.ros.org/users/19256/kasra/) on 2014-07-15**:
global_costmap, local_cost_map, and TrajectoryPlannerROS (They are set in move_base.launch)

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-07-16**:
Can you post the output of `rosparam get /move_base` (once the code is running)

**Comment by [Kasra](https://answers.ros.org/users/19256/kasra/) on 2014-07-16**:
David, I only can put a few characters here so I uploaded the output:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/93wv296sfkb90b2/move_base_param.txt
Thanks

**Comment by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on 2016-06-29**:
@donmrsir , there are some mix-up in here. I'm confused. [etian's answer (http://answers.ros.org/question/9432/navigation-stack-with-gmapping/?answer=13850#post-id-13850)  indicates that we can use gmapping and navigation at the same time, no need to change static map to false

**Comment by [donmrsir](https://answers.ros.org/users/19553/donmrsir/) on 2016-06-29**:
@bsk yes sure, he is right. The thing is that for navigation with gmapping you can use static map false, which mean that your system is in charge of constructing the map while navigation, or static map true, which means that you already have the map of the environment and the navigation use that map

**Comment by [donmrsir](https://answers.ros.org/users/19553/donmrsir/) on 2016-06-29**:
The problem here, if i remember correctly, is that op didnt have a static map, so his only option was to use static map false